# how to get a part of vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, scilab

I want to get parts of a vector `V` with width `W`
As a result, I want to get `M = N*M`, so that if I say `M(2,:)`, I will get all the values of `V(2*W : 3*W)`.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean, but does

```
M = reshape(V, W,[]);
```

come close? Otherwise, try

```
M = reshape(V, W,[]).';
```

or

```
M = reshape(V, [],W);
```

Comment: It comes close but produces a W-by-N matrix (where W*N = length(V)). I think the author wants `M = permute(reshape(V, W, []), [2 1])`.

Comment: @sigma: Wow, that's a complicated way of writing `reshape(V,W,[])'` :) Anyway, you might be right, editing.

Comment: Ah you're also right of course, my MATLAB skills are a little rusty I guess ;)

Comment: I'm using scilab, so I used the function "matrix"  it the synonym of Matlab reshape . thanks again